# Flash loan on Pancakeswap utilizing equalizer.finance provider

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I'm trying to write a smart contract on Remix-Ethereum IDE to do a Flash loan on Pancakeswap utilizing equalizer.finance provider.

the smart contract function is to

1. borrow token1
2. swap token1 with token2
3. swap token2 with token3
4. swap token3 with token1
5. repay token1+fee
6. allow sender to withdraw profit if there is any.

please have a look and help me modify the solidity code to achieve this. appreciate the community support.

here is the drafted code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

import './UniswapV2Library.sol';
import './interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol';
import './interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol';
import './interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol';
import './interfaces/IERC20.sol';

interface IERC20 {
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external returns (bool success);
}

contract Arbitrage {

  address public pancakeFactory; IUniswapV2Router02 public pancakeV2Router;
  address public owner;
    /**
     * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

  constructor(address _pancakeFactory, address _pancakeV2Router) public {
    pancakeFactory = _pancakeFactory;  
    pancakeV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(_pancakeV2Router);
    admin = msg.sender;
  }

interface IERC3156FlashBorrower {
   /**
     * @dev Receive a flash loan.
     * @param initiator The initiator of the loan.
     * @param token The loan currency.
     * @param amount The amount of tokens lent.
     * @param fee The additional amount of tokens to repay.
     * @param data Arbitrary data structure, intended to contain user-defined parameters.
     * @return The keccak256 hash of "ERC3156FlashBorrower.onFlashLoan"
     */
    function onFlashLoan(
        address initiator,
        address token1,
        address token2,
        address token3,
        address _to,
        uint256 _amount1,
        uint256 _amount2,
        uint256 _amount3,
        uint256 fee,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external returns (bytes32);
}

interface IERC3156FlashLender {
   function flashLoan(
        IERC3156FlashBorrower receiver,
        address token1,
        uint256 amount1,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external returns (bool);
}
/*
*  FlashBorrowerExample is a simple smart contract that enables
*  to borrow and returns a flash loan.
*/
contract FlashBorrowerExample is IERC3156FlashBorrower {
    uint256 MAX_INT = 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff;
     //address private constant UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER = 0x9Ac64Cc6e4415144C455BD8E4837Fea55603e5c3;
    // address private constant WBNB = 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c;
    // @dev ERC-3156 Flash loan callback
    //For `flashloanProviderAddress, search for FlashLoanProvider here:
    //https://docs.equalizer.finance/equalizer-deep-dive/smart-contracts

    function initiateFlashloan(
      address flashloanProviderAddress, 
      address token1, 
      uint _amount1, 
      bytes calldata data
      ) external {
      IERC3156FlashLender(flashloanProviderAddress).flashLoan(
        IERC3156FlashBorrower(address(this)),
        tokenIn,
        amountIn,
        data
      );
     }


    function onFlashLoan(
        address initiator,
        address sender, 
        address token1,
        address token2,
        address token3,
        address _to,
        uint256 _amount1,
        uint256 _amount2,
        uint256 _amount3,
        uint256 fee,
        bytes calldata data
        ) external override returns (bytes32) {

        // Set the allowance to payback the flash loan
        IERC20(_tokenIn).approve(msg.sender, MAX_INT);

        address pairAddress = IUniswapV2Factory(pancakeFactory).getPair(token1, token2);
         require(pairAddress != address(0), 'This pool does not exist');

        IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress).swap(
        _amount1, 
        _amount2, 
        address(this), 

        address pairAddress = IUniswapV2Factory(pancakeFactory).getPair(token3, token2);
         require(pairAddress != address(0), 'This pool does not exist');

        IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress).swap(
        _amount3, 
        _amount2, 
        address(this), 

        address[] memory path = new address[](3);
        uint amountToken1 = _amount1 == 0 ? _amount1 : _amount1;
    
        address token1 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token1();
        address token2 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token2();

        uint amountToken2 = _amount2 == 0 ? _amount2 : _amount2;
    
        address token3 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token3();
        address token2 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token2();

       require(
       msg.sender == UniswapV2Library.pairFor(pancakeFactory, token1, token2), 
       'Unauthorized'
        ); 
       uint amountRequired1 = UniswapV2Library.getAmountsIn(
       pancakeFactory, 
       amountToken1, 
       token.approve(address(pancakeV2Router), amountToken1);

       require(
       msg.sender == UniswapV2Library.pairFor(pancakeFactory, token3, token2), 
       'Unauthorized'
        ); 
       uint amountRequired2 = UniswapV2Library.getAmountsIn(
       pancakeFactory, 
       amountToken2, 
       token.approve(address(pancakeV2Router), amountToken2);

       path
       )[0];
       uint amountReceived0 = pancakeV2Router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
       amountToken1, 
       amountRequired1, 
       path, 
       msg.sender, 
       block.timestamp
       )[1];
       uint amountReceived1 = pancakeV2Router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
       amountToken2, 
       amountRequired2, 
       path, 
       msg.sender, 
       block.timestamp
       )[2];

       IERC20 otherToken = IERC20(_amountIn == 0 ? token1 : token2);
       otherToken.transfer(msg.sender, amountRequired2);
       otherToken.transfer(tx.origin, amountReceived1 - amountRequired2);
       }

       // Return success to the lender, he will transfer get the funds back if allowance is set accordingly
       
       return keccak256('ERC3156FlashBorrower.onFlashLoan');
       }

    function withdraw(address recipient, address token, uint amount) external {
      require(msg.sender == admin, 'only admin');
      IERC20(token).transfer(recipient, amount);
      }
}
```

Comment: correction" 1- borrow token1 
2- swap token1 with token2 
3- swap token2 with token3
4- swap token3 with token1
5- repay token1+fee 
6- allow sender to withdraw profit if there is any.
"